# Tasks spawned from a request thread accessing a common store

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, task, httpcontext

I'm working on some code which could be thought of as a message bus. Everything has been working fine until I started playing around with Tasks.

In my particular implementation, as I am in a web context, I am piggy backing onto off `HttpContext.Current.Items` to store the messages throughout the lifetime of a request till I get the messages out at the end of a request. As you can imagine when I start using async Tasks, and operations happen on other threads what I have breaks down.

I understand why this occurs, but I want to come up with a solution which doesn't require me to pass the message bus into every Task.

I don't mind changing the implementation not to use `HttpContext.Current.Items`, but the semantics should work the same. Specifically that I have a store that lives for the lifetime of a request, and that threads spawned from the main request thread can access.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can do this?

As a side point, if a request spawns a log running task and the request returns before the task finishes, if that task try's to find the store, I would image that the store would be null of throw an exception.

Comment: How many messages you are receiving per one request? Do you use one async task per one message?